# Finding a value in cell B(x) and replace value in C(x). Offset by 1

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to ask for some excel VB help.

I have a column B in the range B1:B31. The text contains the words "Enabled", or "Disabled".  My goal is that when a button is clicked, the code would loop through all the values in the range B1:B31, and if it finds the text "Enabled", it will replace the next column (same row) over with a value.  I believe this is offset (0,1).

Example.  So as the code is scanning the range, it comes across cell B3, if it find the word "Enabled" in this cell, then it will insert ] the value from the default time estimate into cell C3.

Here is an illustration:
[image]

Comment: Can you please show how your loop is currently set up? So many ways to do this that it wouldn't do you any good to give you 20 answers and only 1 is compatible to your issue. A `For Var = 1 To ...` and `Cells(Var, "C")` is usually a good way to loop rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Offset you could do it in this case like that

```
Sub SetIt()

    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = Range("B1:C31")

    Dim sngRow As Range
    For Each sngRow In rg.Rows
        If sngRow.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Enabled" Then sngRow.Cells(1, 2).Value = 1
    Next

End Sub
```

With Offset it would look like

```
'With offset
Sub UseOffset()

    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = Range("B1:B31")

    Dim sngCell As Range
    For Each sngCell In rg
        If sngCell.Value = "Enabled" Then sngCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = 1
    Next

End Sub
```

A third way could be to use arrays

```
'With Array
Sub UseArr()

    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = Range("B1:C31")

    Dim vDat As Variant
    vDat = rg.value2

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(vDat) To UBound(vDat)
        If vDat(i, 1) = "Enabled" Then vDat(i, 2) = 1
    Next i

    rg.value2 = vDat
End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't you prefer `vDat = rg.Value` and `rg.Value = vDat`?

Comment: Yes, right, certainly better resp. clearer as one does not use any default properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub MatchValue()
Dim i As Integer
Dim cellValue As String
Dim compValue As String
i = 2
compValue = "ENABLED"
Do While i < 34
cellValue = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value
If UCase(cellValue) = compValue Then
Sheet1.Cells(i, 3) = "True"
Else
Sheet1.Cells(i, 3) = "False"
End If
i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```